# Update strategy Python application + Ember frontend on BeagleBone

Tags: python, deployment, updates, beagleboneblack, yocto

For the moment I've created an Python web application running on uwsgi with a frontend created in EmberJS. There is also a small python script running that is controlling I/O and serial ports connected to the beaglebone black.

The system is running on debian, packages are managed and installed via ansible, the applications are updated also via some ansible scripts. With other words, updates are for the moment done by manual work launching the ansible scripts over ssh.

I'm searching now a strategy/method to update my python applications in an easy way and that can also be done by our clients (ex: via webinterface). A good example is the update of a router firmware. I'm wondering how I can use a similar strategy for my python applications.

I checked Yocto where I can build my own linux with but I don't see how to include my applications in those builds, and I don't wont to build a complete image in case of hotfixes.

Anyone who has a similar project and that would like to share with me some useful information to handle some upgrade strategies/methods?

Answer (score 0):

A natural strategy would be to make use of the package manager also used for the rest of the system. The various package managers of Linux distributions are not closed systems. You can create your own package repository containing just your application/scripts and add it as a package source on your target. Your "updater" would work on top of that.

This is also a route you can go when using yocto.